# Remove items from a listbox if it appears in another

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, listbox

I have 2 listbox's on my form. The first populates from an array and displays files names that relate to the value of a Date Time picker. When that item is double clicked it moves over to the 2nd list box, clears from the 1st and the relevant files are transferred from one directory to another. The problem I have is that as the population is part of the load event once the application is closed and then re-opened the files names appear in both listbox's.

Is there a way to say if the object appears in 1 textbox then it shouldn't appear in the other?

I've tried the following but re-opening still displays the object in both

```
 Dim item As Object

        For Each item In lstPlanned.Items
            If lstProgress.Contains(item) Then
                lstPlanned.Items.Remove(item)
            End If
        Next
```

For the 2nd listbox I'm using the following to populate it

```
For Each Dir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(aMailbox)
        Dim dirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Dir)
        lstProgress.Items.Add(dirInfo.Name)
```

Full Load code as follows

```
Private Sub Main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim loaddate As String = Calendar.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yy")

    ReDim AllDetail(0 To 0)
    numfiles = 0


    lstPlanned.Items.Clear()


   Dim allfiles = lynxin.GetFiles("*.txt")
    ReDim AllDetails(allfiles.Count)

    lstProgress.Items.Clear()

    lstPlanned.Items.Add("No Jobs Planned Today!")
    lstPlanned.Enabled = False

    For Each txtfi In (allfiles)
        Dim allLines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(txtfi.FullName)

        AllDetails(numfiles) = New FileDetail()

        AllDetails(numfiles).uPath = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left((txtfi.FullName), Len(txtfi.FullName) - 4)

        AllDetails(numfiles).uFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(txtfi.Name)

        Dim line = allLines.Where(Function(x) (x.StartsWith("unitname="))).SingleOrDefault()
        If line IsNot Nothing Then
            AllDetails(numfiles).uName = line.Split("="c)(1)
        End If

        line = allLines.Where(Function(x) (x.StartsWith("unitcode="))).SingleOrDefault()
        If line IsNot Nothing Then
            AllDetails(numfiles).uCode = line.Split("="c)(1)
        End If

        line = allLines.Where(Function(x) (x.StartsWith("opername="))).SingleOrDefault()
        If line IsNot Nothing Then
            AllDetails(numfiles).uOps = line.Split("="c)(1)
        End If

        line = allLines.Where(Function(x) (x.StartsWith("plandate="))).SingleOrDefault()
        If line IsNot Nothing Then
            AllDetails(numfiles).uPlan = line.Split("="c)(1)
        End If

        line = allLines.Where(Function(x) (x.StartsWith("cliecode="))).SingleOrDefault()
        If line IsNot Nothing Then
            AllDetails(numfiles).uClient = line.Split("="c)(1)
        End If

        If AllDetails(numfiles).uPlan = loaddate Then

            lstPlanned.Items.Remove("No Jobs Planned Today!")
            lstPlanned.Enabled = True
            lstPlanned.Items.Insert(0, AllDetails(numfiles).uName & " - " & AllDetails(numfiles).uCode & " - " & AllDetails(numfiles).uOps)
            numfiles = numfiles + 1

        End If

    Next


    For Each Dir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(aMailbox)
        Dim dirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Dir)
        lstProgress.Items.Add(dirInfo.Name)

        Dim item As Object

        For Each item In lstPlanned.Items
            If lstProgress.Contains(item) Then
                lstPlanned.Items.Remove(item)
            End If
        Next
    Next

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Tinstaafl

Your answer works a treat.

I also adapted your first edit to

```
Dim RootDir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(aMailbox)
    For Each Dir As IO.DirectoryInfo In RootDir.GetDirectories
        lstProgress.Items.Add(Dir.Name)
        'item defaults to object, no need to explicitly declare it
        For Each item In New System.Collections.ArrayList(lstPlanned.Items)
            If lstProgress.Items.Contains(item) Then
                lstPlanned.Items.Remove(item)
            End If
        Next

    Next
```

amending the following line

```
 For Each item In New System.Collections.ArrayList(lstPlanned.Items)
```

Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome.  See my last edit I eliminated the extra For Each loop

Comment: @tinstaafl Come up with a bit of an issue. If there are 2 items in the listbox when I now double click it removes both and not just the selected?

Comment: Try using RemoveAt(selectedindex) or something similar, which looks only at the specific index not the item itself.

Comment: I added some other enhancements for you to look at.

Answer (score 1):

The Contains method of a listbox checks the controls collections not the items collection.  It should have been `lstProgress.Items.Contains(item)`.  Also you can use GetDirectories of the DirectoryInfo class to get the directoryinfo objects directly.

Checking to see if lstPlanned contains each item as you add it to lstProgress will eliminate the extra loop, which wouldn't work right anyway, because you're not allowed to modify the iterated collection in a For Each loop.

I was looking over your code and noticed an improvement that could be made.  Using the LINQ extension methods each you want to add a property value means a lot of extra iterating through each file line collection.  Using select means you only iterate through the collection once.

```
    For Each txtfi In (allfiles)
        Dim allLines() As String = File.ReadAllLines(txtfi.FullName)

        AllDetails(numfiles) = New FileDetail()

        AllDetails(numfiles).uPath = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Left((txtfi.FullName), Len(txtfi.FullName) - 4)

        AllDetails(numfiles).uFile = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(txtfi.Name)
        AllDetails(numfiles).uPlan = allLines.Where(Function(x) (x.StartsWith("plandate="))).SingleOrDefault().Split("="c)(1)
          If AllDetails(numfiles).uPlan = loaddate Then
            For Each line In allLines
                If line Is Not Nothing Then
                    Dim fields As String() = line.Split("="c)
                    Select Case fields(0)
                        Case "unitname"
                            AllDetails(numfiles).uName = fields(1)
                        Case "unitcode"
                            AllDetails(numfiles).uCode = fields(1)
                        Case "opername"
                            AllDetails(numfiles).uOps = fields(1)
                        Case "plandate"
                            AllDetails(numfiles).uPlan = fields(1)
                        Case "cliecode"
                            AllDetails(numfiles).uClient = fields(1)
                    End Select
                End If
            Next
            lstPlanned.Items.Remove("No Jobs Planned Today!")
            lstPlanned.Enabled = True
            lstPlanned.Items.Insert(0, AllDetails(numfiles).uName & " - " & AllDetails(numfiles).uCode & " - " & AllDetails(numfiles).uOps)
            numfiles = numfiles + 1
        End If
    Next
    Dim RootDir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(aMailbox)
    For Each Dir As IO.DirectoryInfo In RootDir.GetDirectories
        Dim item = Dir.Name
        lstProgress.Items.Add(item)
        If lstPlanned.Items.Contains(item) Then
            lstPlanned.Items.Remove(item)
        End If
    Next
```